# Scrapy - list returns None - index out of range

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have two items in my list which do or do not exist. How do I write a check for list?

Items look like this

```
    item['BusinessType'] = response.xpath('//div//following-sibling::p//text()').extract()[3]
    item['BusinessArea'] = response.xpath('//div//following-sibling::p//text()').extract()[4]
```

Sometimes list member [3] or [4] does not exists, therefore Scrapy fails with

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried few different approaches, but each fails. I do not understand why. Specifying response.xpath as local variable and checking with

```
        if biz_type:
            item['BusinessType'] = biz_type
        else:
            biz_type_none = "None"
            item['BusinessType'] = biz_type_none
        if biz_area:
            item['BusinessArea'] = biz_area
        else:
            biz_area_none = "None"
            item['BusinessArea'] = biz_area_none
```

Fails. Scrapy complains about list still being out of range.

How do i make a correct checking in list extraction process?

EDIT: Full function below. This is last function in 'chain'. It visits 3 pages in previous steps and passes items using meta.

```
    def trust_data(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item ['Access'] = response.xpath('//div//following-sibling::p//text()').extract()[1]
        item ['Feedback'] = response.xpath('//div//following-sibling::p//text()').extract()[2]        
        texts = response.xpath('//div//following-sibling::p//text()').get()

        if len(texts) >= 4:
           item['BusinessType'] = texts[3]
        if len(texts) >= 5:
           item['BusinessArea'] = texts[4]

        yield item
```

Another thing,

```
print(texts, 'lenght is', len(texts))
(u'5600', 'lenght is', 4)
```

Lenght == 4, list is complete

```
>>> print(texts, 'lenght is', len(texts))
(u'0', 'lenght is', 1)
```

Lenght == 1, list is incomplete (It doesnt have tags i want to include in my items)

But condition

`if len(texts) == 1` is always satisfied, and whatever i want to do next will be completed for all of my items. Example:

```
        if len(texts) == 4:
           if len(texts) >= 4:
              item['BusinessType'] = texts[3]
           if len(texts) >= 5:
              item['BusinessArea'] = texts[4]
        else:
           item['BusinessType'] = "None"
           item['BusinessArea'] = "None"
```

This fills both item with "None" in all possible cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you access an index, make sure the corresponding list is long enough:

```py
texts = response.xpath('//div//following-sibling::p//text()').getall()
item['BusinessType'] = texts[3] if len(texts) >= 4 else 'None'
item['BusinessArea'] = texts[4] if len(texts) >= 5 else 'None'
```

Comment: ````IndexError: string index out of range```` I also tried adding ````else```` specifying ````None```` if len <3, but error still stays.

Comment: One suggestion. List has total of 5 items. [0],[1],[2], are always there, [3] and [4] are sometimes missing. In function i look for each of those items. Adding ````is None```` to response also fails if item [3] or [4] does not exists.

Comment: Added a description, and fixed the issue (len() must be ≥ 4 to access list[3]).

Comment: I tried that. Out of range error is gone, but Scrapy omits [3] and [4] from every page, not only ones where its missing. I've edited original post and added whole function in question.

Comment: That’s because of your `if len(texts) == 4:`. I’ve updated the response, try this approach instead.

Comment: No more out of range error, but now every item gets filled with ````None````

Comment: SOLVED. Problem was ````get()````, in my case i needed ````getall()````. ````get() ````was causing list to be never longer than 3, ````getall()```` correctly parses all of the list, now your conditionals work! Thanks for you input, it was crucial for solving it. I am marking your solution as correct.